# Insert intention lock causes deadlock with composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to ask for help :)

Two INSERT statements are issued simultaneously by 2 users into a doctrine-generated many-to-many table:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2) VALUES (2271885, 16678); <-- user 1
INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2) VALUES (2271883, 2550); <-- user 2
```

A deadlock occurs (it is a write-heavy table), and the analysis reveals that both transactions attempt to write into the same space in the table:

```
*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 178586 page no 9618 n bits 176 index PRIMARY of table `my_company`.`my_table`...

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 178586 page no 9618 n bits 176 index PRIMARY of table `my_company`.`my_table`...
```

I guess I am struggling to understand why the deadlock occurs in the first place. It is a classic doctrine many-to-many table, nothing fancy.

Yes, it is write-heavy, but then againt, the MySQL documentation clearly states this about [insert intention locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-insert-intention-locks):

> Suppose that there are index records with values of 4 and 7. Separate
> transactions that attempt to insert values of 5 and 6, respectively,
> each lock the gap between 4 and 7 with insert intention locks prior to
> obtaining the exclusive lock on the inserted row, but do not block
> each other because the rows are nonconflicting.

Why would MySQL calculate that `(2271885, 16678)` and `(2271883, 2550)` are going to end up in the same gap?

The only thing I can think of is that we are dealing with composite primary key instead of a simple integer? What is the solution here? Drop the primary key and create an auto-increment?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am facing this. Did you find why this is happening or if there's a workaround?